# Position element outside of parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a collapsable sidebar with bootstrap and i'm trying to let a submenu pop out of the sidebar when the sidebar is toggled to a mini navigation.

Example: http://niftyfifty.nl/sidebar/

When the window size is > 767 and you click on the toggle button the sidebar shrinks to a mini navigation. When you then hover over the gears icon (settings) the submenu will show in the sidebar to the right of the icon (you can see this by scrolling to the right when hovering the icon). I want this submenu to show outside of the sidebar. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're going for but you can position the settings sub menu outside the sidebar with the following steps.

First you need to set

```
overflow:visible;
```

for the sidebar-wrapper so that items that go outside the div can still be seen. Than you need to re position the sub menu so that it pops up where you want it.
First make sure the < li > element for settings is

```
position:relative;
```

you can do this for all < li > elements if all sub menus are gonna behave this way. Then set the < ul class="collapse in" >

```
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:-97px;          (the width of the sub-menu)
```

this will set the start position of the sub menu div at the top right corner of the settings button. Now when you highlight settings the menu appears next to it rather than below it

Comment: Dang, how could i have missed this.. Updated the example; it's working now :) Thanks!